# I can't get to WEB UI of the IDU-100 Wi-Fi router

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

I have an IDU-100 Wi-Fi router (but I do not have a network from Polsat/Plus, but a cable).  According to [the instructions](http://www.cyfrowypolsat.pl/CMS/media/img/v4/imgRD/obrazki/rozne/internet-domowy-instrukcja-obslugi-15012014.pdf), WEBUI is at `http://192.168.0.1`, but the address does not load, returning: `Connection could not be established.` This address is also listed on the router itself.

On Windows from cmd > `ipconfig` the network gate is `http://192.168.20.1` but it also doesn't work.   In addition, I tried to enter various IP suggested on the net but did not hit.

`ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.20.1 dev enp0s7 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.20.1 dev enp0s7 proto dhcp src 192.168.20.217 metric 1024 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-9fdd10e7b20b proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-bcf16136608d proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 
192.168.20.0/24 dev enp0s7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.216 metric 100 
192.168.20.1 dev enp0s7 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.20.217 metric 1024
```

I restart the router (5 seconds) but it doesn't work, the page is still not loading.  Internet in the computer over the cable and on the phone over WiFi works without any problem out of the box.

How to get to WEBUI?

Comment: Are there any other routers, switches, range extenders, or similar devices between your computer and the IDU-100?

Comment: No. The computer is connected directly to this router.

Comment: Since the default WebUI address listed on the router does not work, the router has been customized and default settings changed. _I'm unable to find an english language version of the router's manual or any info regarding the router, so some many not apply:_ It could be: (1) the WebUI has been placed on a management-only vLAN to firewall traffic to the WebUI; or (2) The WebUI was disabled by the ISP; or (3) webserver serving the WebUI was disabled via SSH for security, requiring manual starting of the webserver via SSH.  Whatever the reason, resetting the router to default will solve the issue

Comment: @JW0914 After all, I wrote that the restart does not help at all, nothing and nothing changes.

Comment: @Jej I said _reset_ **not** _reboot_, as in resetting it to factory defaults.  There should be a small button on the rear of the router that you'll press with the end of a paperclip, holding it for 15s - 45s (it will say in the manual), at which point the router will reboot and you'll navigate to `https://192.168.0.1`.  WebUI pages should _never_ be accessed via plain HTTP, as it will send root's/admin's password via plaintext.

Comment: In manual restet is 2 sec or 5 sec.  
I tried both options. I tried to enter via https and it doesn't change anything, it works exactly the same.  What to do?

Comment: @Jej There is no way a factory reset will not reset it to its default WebUI IP, unless it's been flashed with custom firmware.  Has this ever been flashed with OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Tomato, etc.?  Is the sticker on the bottom of the router the one the router came with from the OEM?  Otherwise, something is missing informational wise from the described problem.  Your best solution is to reach out to the tech support dept of the manufacturer, as you need to troubleshoot, which can't be done effectively on StackExchange.

Comment: @JW0914 From the out of the box there was this problem. Nothing was changed at all. Actually, I don't know exactly what the producer is. The name is "IDU-100 Wi-Fi router".

Comment: @Jej you'll need to find out who the manufacturer is and contact them